# Ruby Array Delete at

Tags: ruby, arrays

In the irb prompt:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array << 0
array.sort
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

I fully understand the above, but when I do this:

```
array.delete_at(2)
```

it deletes 3 in the array. 
If the first is considered 1, why the number 3 was removed instead of number 1?

Comment: are you sure that 3 was removed? it had to remove 2 instead of 1

Comment: Hi. Let me restate: it deletes the number 3 in the array. So yes, the number 3 was removed. If I types: array.sort, it gives: [0,1,2,4,5]

Comment: You want `sort!` rather than `sort`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `array.sort` doesn't save the sorted array, it just returns it. This means that when you call `array.delete_at(2)`, your array is still `[1,2,3,4,5,0]`. What you want to call is `array.sort!`, which sorts and modifies your original array to become `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and puts `2` where you expect to find it.

Comment: Thanks guys! The above answer is the same as below so the first one is clear. It is ashamed that the lynda program says nothing about "array.sort!"

Answer (score 2):

`array,sort` *returns* a new array, it does not modify the original.  If you want the mutating version then you use `array.sort!`.  Otherwise, you would write:

```
array = array.sort
```

But, in this case, you're better off with simply:

```
array.sort!
```

Also...

> If the first is considered 1, why the number 3 was removed instead of number 1?

Arrays in Ruby are zero-indexed, i.e., the first index is 0.  Index 2 (in your sorted array which includes 0) would be 2, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

`array.sort` doesn't change your array. So when running `delete_at(2)`, your array still is `[1,2,3,4,5,0]`. To sort and "save" your array, use `sort!` instead.